# Discord.js, issuance of rights upon waking the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can’t understand how to make sure that when the bot wakes up, it creates a role with administrator rights and issues it to the specified user. Help please.

Comment: What do you mean by "wakes up", and what specified user? Please give us more context for your question, we do not know the situation behind anything you want, only what you have typed here.

Comment: @Snel23, When waking up, the bot must first create a role with administrator rights, and then issue it to a specific user, making it all automatic, without the intervention of the user himself.

Comment: It cannot be completely automatic, as a user would have to give the bot Admin privileges to be able to grant an admin role.

Comment: @Snel23, not necessarily, since as soon as a bot is invited to a server it gets a role with all of the permissions specified in the invite link, so It's possible, but the question is still too broad.